# Spectrum of a differential operator on $L^2(0, \infty)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, differential-operators

Let $A:H^n(0, \infty) \subset L^2(0, \infty) \to L^2(0, \infty)$ be the differential operator defined by
$$Af:= \sum_{j=0}^na_j f^{(j)}$$
for all $f \in H^n(0, \infty),$ where $a_j \in \mathbb{C}$ and $a_n \neq 0$. I need to show that $$\sigma(A)= \{ P(iz) : \mbox{Im}(z) \geq 0\}$$
if $P(z):= a_0 + a_1z+\cdots+a_nz^n$. I have shown that  $S:=\{ P(iz) : \mbox{Im}(z) \geq 0\} \subseteq \sigma(A)$ and that if $\lambda \notin S$ then $(A-\lambda I)^{-1}: R(A-\lambda I) \subseteq L^2(0, \infty) \to L^2(0, \infty)$ is a bounded operator and $R(A-\lambda I)$ is closed, but I am struggling to show that $R(A-\lambda I)=L^2(0, \infty)$ if $\lambda \notin S$.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: When $\lambda \not\in \sigma(A)$, you expect the image of $A-\lambda I$ to be all of $L^2$. The image of the resolvent would then be all of the **domain** of $A$ (or more specifically the appropriate closure of $A$), which for unbounded operators is smaller than $L^2$ itself. I hope I didn't misunderstand what you wrote in the question.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine: I think that the notation $R(A-\lambda I)$ in the question means the range of $A-\lambda I$. The OP does not seem to use the letter $R$ to denote the resolvent.

Comment: @Mainkit: Have you tried to explicitly solve the equation $Au-\lambda u =f$ (where $f\in L^2$), and to show that the solution $u$ is in $H^n$ if $\lambda\not\in S$?

Comment: @JochenGlueck: I see, thanks! The notation was a bit confusing. But then, if one already knows that that $(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$ exists and is bounded, it's domain is already all of $L^2$. End of story. In a way, this is rephrasing of Jochen's last comment.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine Why you can say that if $(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$ exists and is bounded then $D((A-\lambda I)^{-1})=L^2(0, \infty)$?. I say that $(A-\lambda I)$ exists only on $R(A-\lambda I)$.

Comment: @JochenGlueck I have not tried. Maybe I can use Fourier Transform to give an expression for $u$.

Comment: @Mainkit: if the resolvent is bounded, but only defined on a dense domain, then it has a unique extension to all of $L^2$ by continuity.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine But I don't know if $R(A-\lambda I)$ is dense in $L^2(0, \infty)$

Comment: @Mainkit: the domain where the resolvent is defined depends on how it is constructed, and may be different from the range of $(A-\lambda I)$. For instance, in your case, the resolvent may be defined via a formula based on the Fourier transform or via the "variation of constants" formula. I presume that this is how you proved the existence of the resolvent in the first place. Well, these formulas lend themselves to checking boundedness on **some** dense domain. The relevant details are left to you as an exercise.